# ¿Cómo consigo que el condicional xsl:if, funcione en xsl?

Tags: xml, xslt, xsl

tengo una duda con mi código xsl. Necesito que el condicional xsl:if, me arroje los resultados de los vehículos por marca (concatenado con modelo a través de un guión -), y que también me muestre aquellos sin guión. Este es mi código xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="actividadCoches.xsl"?>
<VEHICULOS>
  <MARCA code="7708" nombre="Volvo">
    <MODELO ref="0801">EX90 Eléctrico</MODELO>
    <CONCESIONARIO>CONCESIONARIO VOLVO</CONCESIONARIO>
    <DIRECCION>Avda. Volvo</DIRECCION>  
  </MARCA>
  <MARCA code="7800">
    <MODELO ref="0840">Tesla Model 3</MODELO>
    <CONCESIONARIO>CONCESIONARIO TESLA</CONCESIONARIO>
     <DIRECCION>Ctra. Tesla</DIRECCION>
    </MARCA>
  <MARCA code="7804" nombre="Citroën">
   <MODELO ref="0810">SUV C3 Aircross</MODELO>
    <CONCESIONARIO>CONCESIONARIO CITROËN</CONCESIONARIO>
    <DIRECCION>Paseo Citroen </DIRECCION>   
    </MARCA>
  <MARCA code="7208">
   <MODELO ref="0890">Hyundai i20</MODELO>
    <CONCESIONARIO>CONCESIONARIO HYUNDAI</CONCESIONARIO>
   <DIRECCION>POL. IND. Hyundai sur</DIRECCION>
      </MARCA>
</VEHICULOS>
```

He intentado hacer lo siguiente en xsl, añadiendo la sentencia if y concatenando el guión:

```
<xsl:if test="@nombre!= '' ">
<td style="text-transform:uppercase">
<xsl:value-of select=" concat(MODELO,' - ',@nombre)"/>
</td>
```

Pero me suceden dos cosas. Primero, si no hago la sentencia if, me aparecen todos los vehículos y su modelo, pero con el - (aquellos que no tienen MARCA). Segundo, si le aplico el condicional, me salen tan sólo aquellos que tienen MODELO y MARCA.

Debería quedar algo así, pero sin los guiones del recuadro:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Dejo mi xsl, por si sirve también.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <head/>
      <body>
        <h2>VEHICULOS</h2>
        <table border="1">
          <tr bgcolor="#EEEEEE">
            <th style="text-align:center">Code</th>
            <th style="text-align:center">Modelo-Marca</th>
            <th style="text-align:center">Dirección</th>
            <th style="text-align:center">Concesionario</th>            
          </tr>
          <xsl:for-each select="VEHICULOS/MARCA">
            <xsl:sort select="CONCESIONARIO"/>
            <xsl:if test="@nombre!= '' ">              
                <tr>
                  <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="./@code"/>
                  </td>
                  <td style="text-transform:uppercase">
                    <xsl:value-of select=" concat(MODELO,' - ',@nombre)"/>
                  </td>
                  <td style="text-align:center">
                    <i>
                      <xsl:value-of select="DIRECCION"/>
                    </i>
                  </td>
                  <td style="text-align:center">
                    <i>
                      <xsl:value-of select="CONCESIONARIO"/>
                    </i>
                  </td>                  
                </tr>
              </xsl:if>    
          </xsl:for-each>
        </table>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Seguro que es algo sencillo, pero se me está atragantando. Llevo tiempo probando y buscando info, pero no hay manera. Espero puedan ayudarme.

Muchas gracias
Saludos

Answer (score 1):

Podrías utilizar `xsl:choose/xsl:when/xsl:otherwise`; ejemplo:

```
              <td style="text-transform:uppercase">
                <xsl:choose>
                  <xsl:when test="@nombre">
                    <xsl:value-of select="concat(MODELO,' - ',@nombre)"/>
                  </xsl:when>
                  <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:value-of select="MODELO"/>
                  </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
              </td>
```

En contexto:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <head/>
      <body>
        <h2>VEHICULOS</h2>
        <table border="1">
          <tr bgcolor="#EEEEEE">
            <th style="text-align:center">Code</th>
            <th style="text-align:center">Modelo-Marca</th>
            <th style="text-align:center">Dirección</th>
            <th style="text-align:center">Concesionario</th>            
          </tr>
          <xsl:for-each select="VEHICULOS/MARCA">
            <xsl:sort select="CONCESIONARIO"/>
                <tr>
                  <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="./@code"/>
                  </td>
                  <td style="text-transform:uppercase">
                    <xsl:choose>
                      <xsl:when test="@nombre">
                        <xsl:value-of select=" concat(MODELO,' - ',@nombre)"/>
                      </xsl:when>
                      <xsl:otherwise>
                        <xsl:value-of select="MODELO"/>
                      </xsl:otherwise>
                    </xsl:choose>
                  </td>
                  <td style="text-align:center">
                    <i>
                      <xsl:value-of select="DIRECCION"/>
                    </i>
                  </td>
                  <td style="text-align:center">
                    <i>
                      <xsl:value-of select="CONCESIONARIO"/>
                    </i>
                  </td>                  
                </tr>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </table>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Hola Martin, gracias por tu respuesta. Es una forma que desconocía, la tendré en cuenta :). ¿Sería posible hacer lo mismo, pero solamente aplicando el xsl:if? Sin el uso del when, choose... Gracias

Comment: Podrías utilizar `<xsl:value-of select="MODELO"/><xsl:if test="@nombre"><xsl:value-of select="concat(' - ', @nombre)"/></xsl:if>` .